# What is a common or slang or euphemistic term in German for male sexual impotence?

Tags: english-to-german

The word "impotent," in German as in English, has two meanings: powerless in general and sexually incapable. In English there are hundreds of slang terms for this, but I've been unable to find any in German. The word "impotent" itself is too technical for my purpose.

Comment: Common slang: _"Schlappschwanz"_

Comment: While *Schlappschwanz* *(limp-dick)*, taken literally, seems to indicate impotence, I have only ever seen it used metaphorically, as *pussy, wuss, wimp*.

Comment: Could you give some examples for these hundreds of English terms?

Comment: Thinking about German slang terms for "impotent" I could not remember a single one. There are a lot of terms used by people involved in masculinity cult areas of sports to derogate people as *not masculine* (*Warmduscher* and so on), but these seem to avoid direct reference to functions of the sexual organs. Could it be that English (or do you perhaps specifically mean: American English?) has many such terms because there is a special form of male sexualisation in that country?

Comment: PS: Noteworthy in this context is the super-ubiquituos use of *has the balls to...* for actually *has the courage to*, *is brave enough to...*, in - I think especially - American English. The term is recently so over-used  that it is hard to find a different one in popular media. Some people complain (righteously, as I would assume to have the balls to claim) that courage has nothing to do with testosterone levels in one's blood, and that female persons with naturally low testosterone levels can anyway be very courageous or brave. See perhaps Alexandria Ortezio-Cortez.

Comment: In German, the word is not (or maybe very rarely) used for general lack of power.

Comment: The question is confusing. Are you asking about the adjective, the noun, the possessive-noun? Can you give an example sentence where "impotent" does not seem to work? DWDS gives "Erektionsstörung, Potenzstörung, · erektile Dysfunktion" for the noun, and "beischlafsunfähig" for the adjective, neither of which is really preferable except perhaps in formal contexts.

Comment: You wrote that "*impotent*" has two meanings in English - does "*In English there are hundreds of slang terms for this*" refer to one of these meanings or to both of them? And are all the slang terms ambiguous regarding both meanings? And are you asking for German terms that cover both aspects at once or only one  of the two (which)?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I think the only legitimate way to claim that courage has nothing to do with testosterone levels in one's blood is to claim that it isn't actually courage when you enjoy it. (_has nothing to do_ is a very strong statement for something where there is much experimental evidence.) "persons with naturally low testosterone levels can anyway be very courageous or brave" - now that we can agree on.

Comment: @Christian: [Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandria_Ocasio-Cortez).

Answer (score 7):

Wenn jemand impotent ist, dann kriegt der keinen mehr hoch.

Answer (score 2):

wiki DE  [**Tote Hose**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tote_Hose)
"Jugendsprache: Schwunglosigkeit, auch männliche Impotenz"

Answer (score 1):

The OP leaves it open (unless we read only the headline) if he thinks of *impotent* in terms of sexual activity or *impotent* in terms of general inability to act in what area ever.

For the latter, terms in use are

> Waschlappen (m.)
>
> Lusche (f.)

Note that these are explicitely not being understood as refering to sexual activities.

Also there are terms to accuse people of not being physically impressive:

> Hänfling (m.)
>
> Jammergestalt (f.)

Or to behave non-masculinely *

> Jammerlappen (m.)

For direct replacements of *impotent* as an adverb:

> kraftlos
>
> schwach
>
> zerbrechlich
>
> machtlos
>
> passiv

---

- Whatever "masculine" means. This is an open discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Christian Geiselmanns Liste möchte ich ergänzen um

- Eunuch
- Kastrat

die sich insbesondere auf die sexuelle Potenz beziehen, aber auch im übertragenen Sinne benutzt werden.

Answer (score -2):

An euphemistic expression is

> nicht mehr können [er kann nicht mehr]

Only used when addressing the elderly:

> [jenseits von Gut und Böse sein](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gut#Bedeutung4b)

Comment: Yes... of course, when the context is already clear (through previous parts of the conversation), many expressions are possible, e.g. *Er kriegt's nicht mehr gebacken*, *Er kriegt den Motor nicht mehr gestartet*, and so on. But I have never heard anybody using this. I have never heard anybody talking about this, especially not about others in a derogatory way. Hypothesis: we just do not do this. What I have witnessed is an elderly guy in his 80s making an ironic joke about himself.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Abgesehen von medizinischen Fachgesprächen ist es ein Tabu, von Impotenz zu sprechen, insbesondere mit diesem Wort. Wenn schon, wählt man Umschreibungen. Dergleichen höre allerdings auch ich eher nie als selten. Neben der gesprochenen Sprache gibt es aber auch die geschriebene, die die Frage ja nicht ausschließt.